# Variable Comparing With Pointer Reference, C language

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Why `min` is not compared to `*(arr+i)` ?
If statement in this code is not being executed

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i, min;
    int arr[5];
    for (i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);

    min = *(arr);
    for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
    {
        if ( min < *(arr + i) )
        {
            printf("min for %d is %d", i, min);
            min = *(arr + i);
        }
    }

    printf("%d\n", min);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: how do you know it's not compared?

Comment: input `5 4 3 2 1`....then?

Comment: It gives 5. After debugging , any statement inside **if** was not executing.

Comment: You are looking for the maximum and forgot a new line in the first printf, but it works for me: http://ideone.com/ttZEBA

Comment: I am looking for the minimum.

Comment: Your `if` is wrong, if you are looking for the minimum. Your code looks for the maximum.

Comment: Apart from the fault shown in answer, what was wrong with doing `min = arr[0]` followed by `if ( min > arr[i])`? You managed it well enough here `scanf("%d", &arr[i])` without convolutions.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when the code wants a value from the user, the code should always prompt the user, with valid range, etc.   The posted code leaves the user staring at blank screen with a blinking cursor and no indication of what to do next.

Comment: the posted code contains 'magic' numbers (4, 5).  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.   Suggest 1) eliminate all references to 4.  2) use a #define statement to give the magic number 5 a meaningful name, then use that meaningful name throughout the code.  Note: `min < 5` is much clearer than `min <= 4`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is executing, the problem is that your condition is wrong:

```
min=*(arr);
for(i=1;i<=4;i++)
{
    if ( min > *(arr+i) )   // Changed < into >
    {
        printf("min for %d is %d",i,min);
        min = *(arr+i);
    }
}
```

You first take the first element as your minimum. Later, for each element, you need to check if your *current* minimum is **larger** than the current value. If that is the case, you update.